A single standalone python interpreter executable
Basically, solutions like win python and portable-python all depend on shared libraries that need to be on the same level as Python's.
The problem is that I need a single standalone Python interpreter executable to run a big package in Tauri as a sidecar.
Why can't I add the whole folder of Python's (shared libs, bins, etc.)?
Tauri requires a single file to be ran as a sidecar, besides that on Linux and Macos some env vars needs to be set for the python interpreter working correctly; and this is not what I want at all, my application is supposed to be for non-tech savvy people, furthermore I need a specific python version.
Pyinstaller,fx_freeze and nuitka, etc. Are no no goes for me and won't work in my situation.

Any recommended modifications for this question is appreciated.

